# MapThread with several cells as output

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume I have defined the following function:

```
FF[{x_, y_}] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y}
```

I would like to apply `FF` on a list of input such as:

```
XX = {xa, xb, xc}
YY = {ya, yb, yc}
```

In order to do it I input the following syntax:

```
MapThread[FF, {XX, YY}]
```

but as output I get just the first element of the function:

```
{xa^2+ya^3, xb^2+yb^3, xc^2+yc^3}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `MapThread[FF[{##}] &, {XX, YY}]`; alternatively, redefine `FF[]`: `FF[x_, y_] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot kguler this works!!! now to better understand,
what is ACTUALLY the differrence between FF[x_, y_] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y} and the original FF[{x_, y_}] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y} as Mathematica understand it? Doron

Comment: Doron, I guess the 'thank you" and the follow up question were meant for @J.M.:)

Comment: `MapThread[FF, {XX, YY}]` gives `{FF[xa, ya], FF[xb, yb], FF[xc, yc]}`, not `{xa^2+ya^3,xb^2+yb^3,xc^2+yc^3}`. That is, it returns `FF` unevaluated, because `FF` requires a single list as its argument, so it is not defined when it is passed a `Sequence` of two arguments.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use `MapThread` in this case. From the point of functional programming I consider this

```
FF /@ Transpose[{XX, YY}]
```

as more consistent. This is because the signature of `FF`, namely taking a tuple and returning a tuple, is exactly what you want to express mathematically. Therefore, I would not use the solution

```
MapThread[FF[{##}] &, {XX, YY}]
```

because although it works, it has to recreate the tuple parameter by wrapping `FF` with a pure function.

Another point: Maybe you know that most basic operations like multiplication, powers, etc work with list arguments. Thats why you could spare the `Map` (`/@`) of my first example and simply write

```
Transpose[FF[{XX, YY}]]
```

Comment: I think I get it. nevertheless (and I might again be worng...), I think thak fore a more complicate case such as, for example FFFF[x_, y_] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y, x*y^0.5} the Only thing that will work is MapThread[FFFF, {XX, YY}]. right?

Comment: You have almost always several possibilities. For an `f[x_, y_] := {x^2 + y^3, 3.5*x*y, x*y^0.5}` you could write `f @@@ Transpose[{XX, YY}]` too.

Comment: @Doron, I did not want to *force* you in one direction which is the best (because it always depends). I wanted to show you that since we have this [huge amount](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) of functional operations in Mathematica, you should try to implement *your idea*.